# Better estimator of the mean of a distribution

Tags: estimation, monte-carlo, markov-process

Suppose $X_1$, . . . , $X_n$ iid∼ F and $Y_1$, . . . , $Y_n$ is a Markov chain with F as the stationary distribution. Consider two estimates of the mean of F:

$X_m$ $=$ $\frac{1}{n}$$\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$
and $Y_m$ $=$ $\frac{1}{n}$$\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i$
Which estimate is better ( Lower variance) ? 
If Yi's are stationary doesn't it mean their probabilities no longer depend on Yi-1?

Comment: "If Yi's are stationary doesn't it mean their probabilities no longer depend on Yi-1?" Which probability? Can you be more specific.